# Finding div control created by innerhtml from codebehind in aspx vb.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating string value of markup in code behind and insert it by `innerhtml` to div finally in Page_Load method.
I want to put `<asp:ImageButton>` to div created by `innerhtml`. As I can set-up `onClick` method, select a picture for button, etc.

```
markUp += "<td><div runat='server' id='deleteDiv" & row("id") & "'></div>"
result.InnerHtml = markUp (result - DIV element on markup page)
```

after I put:

```
Dim deleteDiv = Me.FindControl("deleteDiv" & row("id"))
                Dim deleteBtn = New ImageButton()
                deleteBtn.ID = "deleteBtn" & row("id")
                deleteDiv.Controls.Add(deleteBtn)
```

If I create div in markup page it works, but this way can not find as it has not been fully loaded and gives an error

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   display.dll but was not handled in user code" on the row
>   "deleteDiv.Controls.Add(deleteBtn)"

How can I program it to be `findcontrol` after page loaded? it goes to `Master_Page_Load` method after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Literal to add controls of text type and combined it with adding ImageButton control.

```
result.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<table class='adminTable'><tr><th width=30px>#</th><th>Name</th><th>File type</th><th>Current</th><th>Delete</th></tr>"))
Dim deleteBtn = New ImageButton()
deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("id", "deleteBtn" & rowid)
deleteBtn.ImageUrl = "img/delete.png"
deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "'deleteBtn_Click'")
result.Controls.Add(deleteBtn)
result.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div></td></tr>"))
```

But now there is another problem. ImageButton created in aspx page calls method from code behind:

```
<asp:ImageButton id='changeMode' runat='server' OnClick='changeModeBtn_Click' />
```

But when I insert button from codebehind it does not call method. There is difference in development tool of Chrome
First becomes like:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$changeMode" id="ctl00_MainContent_changeMode" src="img/switch-on-right1.png" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$changeMode&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Second (created in code):

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" id="deleteBtn1" runat="server" src="img/delete.png" onclick="deleteBtn_Click;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$ctl00&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Question: what is wrong?